# CakePHP Accessing Dynamically Created Tables?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, dynamic

As part of a web application users can upload files of data, which generates a new table in a dedicated MySQL database to store the data in.  They can then manipulate this data in various ways.

The next version of this app is being written in CakePHP, and at the moment I can't figure out how to dynamically assign these tables at runtime.

I have the different database config's set up and can create the tables on data upload just fine, but once this is completed I cannot access the new table from the controller as part of the record CRUD actions for the data manipulate.

I hoped that it would be along the lines of

```
function controllerAction(){ 
$this->uses[] = 'newTable'; 
$data = $this->newTable->find('all'); 

//use data 
}
```

But it returns the error

> Undefined property:
>   ReportsController::$newTable
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   find() on a non-object in
>   /app/controllers/reports_controller.php
>   on line 60

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$this->loadModel('newTable')` to initialize it properly. Cake needs to initialize $this->newTable properly, and call all the callbacks.

Of course, you don't need `$this->uses[] = 'newTable';`, that doesn't do anything except add another value to the $uses array.

Comment: Cool. That's definitely a step in the right direction. Thanks.

The only issue is that this only loads the model if the data table is in the app database, but these dynamic tables are created in their own database so I need to change the useDbConfig of the model somehow...  any ideas?

Comment: Found it.  Thanks for posting, I looked up the API for loadModel() and found ClassRegistry (which is what it calls), that can be passed an array including which datastore to use.

Comment: $this->newTable->useDbConfig = 'otherDatabaseConfigVar';

Comment: Final Solution:

$this->$dataTable = ClassRegistry::init(array('class'=>'newTable', 'ds'=>'dataDB'))
$this->newTable ->find('all');

Comment: hey how did you create your model for that table runtime??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function controllerAction() {
  $data = ClassRegistry::init('ModelNameForNewTable')->find('all');
}
```

If your table is called 'new_tables', your model name should be 'NewTable'